# freeze scrolling for period of time

Tags: javascript, html, css

Wanna make some scroll just like on [this link](http://themewich.com/struck/).
The problem is that i can't prevent from scrolling for 1 sec after switching to different zone. Wrote [some code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e65c2542aae0615e4a4) below already, it works, but have a couple of bugs (in example above you can't do scrolling while zone transition happening. In my code you can. Need to disable a non-pause-transition).

Working on this problem for a while, so will be grateful for any help.

```
var zoneHeight = $('#zone1').height();
zoneHeight += 10; //border


var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

  disableScroll();
  if (scrollPosition > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code

      if(scrollPosition > 0 && scrollPosition < zoneHeight){
        window.scrollTo(0, zoneHeight);        
      }
      else if(scrollPosition > zoneHeight && scrollPosition < zoneHeight * 2){
        window.scrollTo(0, zoneHeight * 2);
      }
  } else {
      // upscroll code

      if(scrollPosition < zoneHeight * 2 && scrollPosition > zoneHeight){
        window.scrollTo(0, zoneHeight);
            }
            else if(scrollPosition < zoneHeight && scrollPosition > 0){
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
   }

  setTimeout(function(){enableScroll()}, 1000);
  lastScrollTop = scrollPosition;
});


// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include the code you've written instead of linking to it, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code and the link could become lost or broken in future, rendering the question less useful.

Comment: That would be really annoying user experience to freeze scrolling. Instead try to disable scroll button when page is loading and enable it when page is loaded.